# io.emit() not emmiting data to all clients

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I am creating a chat application.
In the server, we had an event.

```
io.emit('userAgentConnectMsg', data);
```

In the client, we are listening to this event.

```
socket.on('userAgentConnectMsg', (data) => { console.log(data)} );
```

Suppose think I have two clients connected to server.

If one client gets message another client will not get that.

This is happening randomly.

I changed code from **io.emit** to **io.sockets.emit** still the same issue.

And the worst thing is I am not getting any error either from client or server.
And I am not at all sure where the issue is happening from either it is from server or client.

I did some analysis for socket io before the **io.emit**
I logged `io.sockets.adapter.sids` which basically return all connected socket ids.

the issue is sometimes it shows only some sockets and sometimes it shows empty object.

Some can help me if you have faced the same issue.

Comment: It should be `io.sockets.emit` but you say that also isn't working? Could you share more code? Perhaps a sufficient amount with which to debug

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I cannot share the code but, Its just a basic socket event from the server in the client I am listening to it. Actually I have one doubt to ask. The server is scaled horizontally. Is this could be a problem? Previously it is working fine suddenly the issue came and no errors so I can't event tell where is the issue

Comment: Have you tried broadcast?

socket.broadcast.emit('userAgentConnectMsg', data);

https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/

Comment: it's not broadcast event. it should emit to all clients including itself. But I didn't try broadcast definitely try and will comment the result below.

Comment: Yes, io.emit should work for your use case, was just curious if broadcast had a different result to help with tracing the issue

Comment: I did try the broadcast it's the same issue. But I had one error
`failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 503`
this error means it doesn't connect to WebSockets and its falling back to xhr long polling. So here we are using xhr long polling. Is this may be an issue.

Comment: I have just cleared this error `failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 503`. Then also the same issue.